# How do you create a new script in Greasemonkey 4?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey-4, firefox-57+

Greasemonkey 4.0 has changed its interface, and for the life of me I cannot find any way to create a new script.

[image]

Comment: @BrockAdams, thanks for that comment. Switching to Tampermonkey was a much quicker alternative. Scooter's answer does work, but this is much quicker and more effective, in my case at least.

Comment: Related: [How to Transfer All Greasemonkey userscripts to Tampermonkey on Firefox 57+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317983/how-to-transfer-all-greasemonkey-userscripts-to-tampermonkey-on-firefox-57)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** this was [fixed in version 4.1](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/12/greasemonkey-41-release.html) on 11-Dec-2017 (thankfully someone opened a [bug](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2645) for it)

[image: Greasemonkey 4.1 menu]

---

It really seems like version 4.0 has no way to do this (and is very poorly documented) and so my workaround was just to install a simple/short script that seemed low risk and then just edit that script to make it my own.

I used [this script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/119298) <sup>([source code](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/119298) to check for safety)</sup> and clicked the green "Install" button near the upper right of the page:

[image: The button]

This installed it into Greasemonkey.

After that, you can click on the Greasemonkey toolbar icon, click on the script you just added, and then click "Edit" in the submenu to edit it.

Comment: Thanks, I used your method. Hopefully they'll fix that... Re-creating dozens of scripts isn't particularly fun.

Comment: The install button didn't appear for me.

Comment: @pts, yes it did.  It's hard HTML encoded into that page. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way for me is to move the script to localhost, visit it through the browser and then click on "Install". (script name must be for example "myscript**.user.js**")
https://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:Installing_Scripts

Answer (score 2):

I used Vit Kolos' answer, which worked great. But there is additional information you might need.

(1) Vit's method requires that you have `xampp` or wamp/mamp/lamp installed and running. (Free software - google and install)
(2) Create a folder called by the name of the website (for e.g.: `c:\xampp\htdocs\gm\wnd.com`)
(3) Copy the script into the (for eg) `c:\xampp\htdocs\gm\wnd.com` folder, with the file named (again for eg) `wnd.com.user.js`. 
(4) In the browser address bar, type `localhost/gm/wnd.com` (if that is what you named the folders). 
(5) You should now see the file `wnd.com.user.js` in the list of files - click on it.
(6) You will open the script (text) file - but
(7) At bottom it will count down from 5-to-1 and then display the install button. Nice and neat.

To EDIT your installed script:
(1) Click the GM icon and it will drop down with a list of installed scripts. You should see your script listed there. Click on it, and you will have the option to edit. Or
(2) Navigate to `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\YOUR_OWN_PROFILE.default\gm_scripts\wnd.com\` and edit `wnd.com.user.js` in sublime or atom or Notepad++ or ... <sub>*(If you don't know how to get to `appdata\roaming` then this method is not for you...)*</sub>

Note that if you use jQuery, you should also:

(1) Ensure that your script has jQuery referenced in the header via `@require`, for e.g.:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        wnd.com
// @namespace   wnd.com
// @description wnd.com
// @include     *://*.wnd.*/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$(function(){
    //your script goes here
});
```

Comment: For debugging purpose, [http-server with node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or [SimpleHttpServer with Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) / [http.server with Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) should be much easy to use.