# Greasemonkey Add On does not work properly

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4, firefox-57+

I've installed the Greasemonkey Add On but I can neither install any scripts nor I can create my own scripts. When I click on the Add On in the upper menu bar I see following entries:

- Greasemonkey is active
- New user script ...
- Greasemonkey home page
- Greasemonkey wiki
- Get User Scripts

When I click on "New User Script ..." nothing happens, just sometimes it opens like 5 tabs of an empty script.

I am using Firefox 57.0.2 (64 bit)
and Windows or Ubuntu (latest versions)

Same behavior on both Operating systems

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Simply install Tampermonkey.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296202/how-do-you-create-a-new-script-in-greasemonkey-4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Use Violentmonkey or Tampermonkey instead of Greasemonkey.**

---

Greasemonkey 4 is severely crippled and, frankly, Greasemonkey has been lagging ever further behind Tampermonkey in terms of capabilities and ease -- even before this major break.

In Fact, **[the Greasemonkey team itself recommends that you switch to another engine:](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html)**

> ...but this **will break** some scripts.  If you rely on such scripts, you might want to install [Violentmonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/violentmonkey/) or [Tampermonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/), both of which provide better compatibility for existing scripts.

---

[**Violentmonkey**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/violentmonkey/) is good, if a little unpolished and incomplete. And [it's open source](https://github.com/violentmonkey/violentmonkey).

[**Tampermonkey**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/) is better, and has bested Greasemonkey in ease-of-use and capability for a few years now.  But it's not open source and does more communication with the "mothership". (Nothing nefarious as far as can tell.)

Tampermonkey is also ported to the most number of other browsers, and has easy import/export tools.

Comment: Thank you, its working now, I googled that problem already but couldn't find anything about any problems with greasemonkey

Comment: Some of Greasemonkey's problems are admitted in the GM blog.  You can see more in the bug reports and pull requests, including the "closed" but not fixed ones.  Also compare the GM API docs to the TM API docs.  You'll see that one has much more functionality.  I'd  put together a list but (1) Stack Overflow is not the place for it, (2) Since there are better alternatives than GM, that's where I now concentrate my efforts.

Comment: For Firefox 57.0.3, VM is working for me after GM just served up the raw script text and didn't process or install. Ought to come up with a different name for the software though. Grease I can understand, but 'violent' ? :P